# Plotting issue with multi variables

Tags: plotting

I'm having trouble graphing this function in Mathematica, I'm trying to graph the three below functions but I don't know where I'm going wrong.
[image]

This is the error message I keep getting. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Restart Mathematica to forget all previous assignments that might be saved in cache and then try `==1` instead of `=1` and see what happens. Then look up `==` and `=` in the help system and study those.

Comment: Use `RegionPlot` not `Plot`. For the other question you should define some regions for example: `egg = ImplicitRegion[x^4 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}];`  and `disk = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}];` You can determine that the disk is completely contained inside the egg by doing `RegionMeasure@RegionDifference[disk, egg]` which gives zero showing there's no area left over when you remove the egg from the disk.

Comment: @flinty, `RegionPlot` can plot an inequality that is implicit, May  I ask, what the added benefits of declaring an `ImplicitRegion` are? Is it due to the availability of all the new `Region*` functions that this form of a region is used? Is there a way to do the intersection/measurements with inequalities alone?

Comment: @Syed yes, the ImplicitRegion's are easier though. For the same example, you can reduce the set of points that are in the disk and also NOT in the egg. This returns `False` meaning there are no points, so the disk is entirely contained in the egg: `Reduce[(x^2 + y^2 <= 1) && Not[x^4 + y^2 <= 1]]`

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
ContourPlot[{Abs[x] + Abs[y] == 1,
  x^2 + y^2 == 1,
  x^4 + y^2 == 1}, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5},
       PlotLegends -> {"diamond", "circle", "egg"}]]
```

[image]

or

```
     RegionPlot[{Abs[x] + Abs[y] <= 1,
  x^2 + y^2 <= 1,
  x^4 + y^2 <= 1}, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"diamond", "circle", "egg"}]
```

[image]